# C - Accept Argument of Known Size but Unknown Type

Tags: c, gcc, macros, variadic-functions

I'm interested in creating my own implementation of a doubly-linked list in C. The goal is to make it as flexible and "user" friendly as possible. This means it can't be restricted to one type of data. I'd also like to minimize memory management outside of the list code. That is, I want the list code to handle allocating and freeing any necessary memory. (But, of course, the list could be used to store pointers to dynamically-allocated data.)

I'm using two structs. The "node" struct holds pointers to the node immediately before it and the node immediately following it, a `void*` pointer to the data it contains, and the size of the data. However, because this is C, it can't hold the type of data. The "list" struct keeps track of the beginning and end of the list, the number of elements in the list, and so on. I've already implemented the functions for initializing the list and appending data to the list. The memory allocation and deallocation and linking seem to be working fine, and the lists appear to link to one another properly. The problem is how to actually import the data when creating a list node. Here are the approaches I've considered:

1. Passing a pointer to the data through a `void*` and the size as another argument. This could be made more user-friendly by adding a macro to take the address and size of a variable and pass those to the function. The problem? Not everything I might want to add to the list can have its address taken. For example, consider `list_append(list, 17)`. This should add a new node with an integer payload of value 17 to the end of the list, but it would not work because the integer literal `17` can't have its address taken.
2. Passing the size of the data as one argument and the data itself on the call stack as an extra argument. C supports arguments of unknown number, type, and size though the `...`/`stdarg.h` method. I figured I could use a macro to take the `sizeof()` the item being appended and pass this along with the item itself to the appending function. The problem here is that the varargs macros want me to specify a type (not just the size of the type). So, I did some digging and found that GCC apparently uses the `__builtin_next_arg` macro to implement variable arguments in `stdarg.h`. Obviously, this would make my code dependent on GCC (or, at least, on this particular macro), but it might work at least with this particular compiler. The `__builtin_next_arg` macro allegedly gives the address of the argument following the last named one on the argument list as a `void*`. When I tried this approach on Windows (using MinGW 32-bit), it worked as intended. A simple `memcpy()` from the value given by `__builtin_next_arg` to the newly allocated buffer copied the data. However, when I used GCC 64-bit on Ubuntu, all hell broke loose. `__builtin_next_arg` was giving me addresses very far from where I'd expect the argument to be. The compiler also started occasionally complaining about the second argument to `va_start` wasn't the last argument in the list, despite the fact that I don't even use `va_start` in my code at all. Also, no matter what I did, the values I seemed to be getting were zeros (`NULL`, `0`).

Is there a way I could fix this? What I basically want is a version of `va_arg` that gives the address of the argument on the stack. Other approaches are also acceptable.

In C++, I would be able to use templates to avoid this problem entirely, but I want to use C.

Comment: TL/DR. ADT (Abstract data type) is the keyword.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: TL;DR indeed. But templates are only diet ADT (or was it "light"?).

Comment: Use the language best fitted for your problem. And with an appropriate abstraction level. Otherwise you will soon loose interest and/or motivation and get lost in details. Not to forget about not understanding what you did if you pause for some weeks/months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use the `__builtin_next_arg` here. The reason is that even with `__builtin_next_arg` and such, your *called function* must know the **type of data**.

And no, function arguments are not stored on stack in say Linux x86-64 ABI; the first 6 arguments are provided in registers. And the registers depend on their types, so `float` and `int` are in different register, even though both are of size 4. Sorry, you just cannot do it like this, even in a particular GCC version on this ABI.

---

However if you're using C11, you can use a **macro**, that uses `static_assert` to assert the `sizeof` object passed in; then you can use some `_Generic` tricks to store different types into a `struct` that contains `char contents[sizeof val];`, something like:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VALUE_SIZE (sizeof(int))

struct list;
struct value_type {
    char contents[VALUE_SIZE];
};

int _list_append(struct list *l, struct value_type v);

struct value_type coerce_float(float arg) {
    struct value_type rv;
    memcpy(&arg, rv.contents, sizeof arg);
    return rv;
}

struct value_type coerce_int(int arg) {
    struct value_type rv;
    memcpy(&arg, rv.contents, sizeof arg);
    return rv;
}

static_assert(sizeof(float) == VALUE_SIZE,
              "code relies on float and int being of the same size");

#define coerce_arg(X) (_Generic((X),           \
                          float: coerce_float, \
                          int: coerce_int,      \
                          void*: coerce_int \
                      )((int)X))

#define list_append(L, X) _list_append(L, coerce_arg(X))

list_append(l, 4);
list_append(l, 4.0f);
list_append(l, (void*)0);  // will throw an error since it is not supported
```

This is quite portable, but note that for example MSVC compiler does not even support C99. GCC and LLVM shouldn't have problems. However on the con side, you must add *each* supported compatible type by hand. Including each pointer type, or cast your pointers to say `(void*)`.

---

If you're ok with using only GCC I believe you can write a macro that uses [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) to make a variable of the exact argument type, then `memcpy` its contents directly into this struct.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you either not use `__builtin_*` functions at all or thoroughly study their implementations by reading the docs/gcc sources/asm compiler output of simple functions you code just to see how it works.

First, the behavior of specifically __builtin_next_arg could be completely different between `mingw` and `linux` environment because of different `ABI` in use.

Next, the `__builtin_*` function(s) may be superseded by another one(s) in a different `gcc` version. For example, in gcc-4.8.3 (linux build, to be precise) va_* macroses are implemented using
`__builtin_va_start()`, `__builtin_va_end()` and `__builtin_va_arg()` functions and there is no occurrences of `__builtin_next_arg` in the `gcc` internal header files.